# How to get value from EditText on the activity to use it on another activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-edittext

How to get value from EditText (editProtein) like this

```
protected void protein() {
    EditText editCalorie = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editCalorie);
    double pro = Double.parseDouble(editCalorie.getText().toString());
    EditText editProtein = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editProtein);
    editProtein.setText(Double.toString(pro * 0.25 * 4));
}
```

on the activity to use it on another activity? 
What code should I use on the activity and on another activity, thanks

Comment: did you even do any research before asking the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are quite a few different ways that you can share data between different `Activity` classes. How you do it really depends on your specific application and what sort of lifetime that data should have.

The first way is to pass it to the new `Activity` you launch from the first `Activity` by means of the `putExtras()` method to send arbitrary information to the other activity. To fire up the second `Activity`, you use an `Intent`; what you're doing is packing some additional arbitrary data (in this case perhaps your protein stuff):

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(“some_protein_stuff″, textStringFromYourEditText);

Intent newIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), ActivityClass2.class);
newIntent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivityForResult(newIntent, 0);
```

On ActivityClass2, we can read this parameter using the syntax:

```
Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
String param1 = bundle.getString(“some_protein_stuff″);
```

However, as an alternative, rather than passing the data to the new `Activity` when you invoke it, you may also want to consider using **Shared Preferences**. This is a mechanism by which you can store data very easily in your application by means of key-value pairs. If there is an possibility that you will want to use the value that the user input via the `EditText` in various other `Activity` classes and also want to use that same value when the application is closed down and opened again later, then it will still be available to you, by simply pulling it back out of the Shared Preferences. Preferences are very easy to use and there are various tutorials on SO or elsewhere.

As another alternative, you could consider sharing data like this 'globally' by making a class that extends `android.app.Application`, or create a Singleton class, which achieves a similar result to that.

The first most obvious solution of bundling the data in with the `Intent` when starting the new `Activity` is *probably* what you're after, but the latter two suggestions may also be of interest depending on how your application works and how you want that data to be persisted.

Comment: I am newbie on Android Programming, I got error for this row 
Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();

The method getIntent() is undefined ... otherwise, getIntent() is not a method right? Correct me if I was wrong, Thx Trevor

Answer (score 1):

You can pass values to another activity. Something like:

```
intent.putExtra("CALORIE", calorie);
intent.putExtra("PROTEIN", protein);
```

Corresponding to this, in the activity where you want to use these values, use something like:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras !=null) {
    double calorie = extras.getDouble("CALORIE");
    double protein= extras.getDouble("PROTEIN");
}
```

Comment: I am newbie on Android Programming, I got error for this row Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); The method getIntent() is undefined ... otherwise, getIntent() is not a method right? Correct me if I was wrong, Thx Hermant

Answer (score 0):

EditText extends TextView which has getText method.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getText%28%29